# ASP.NET entity framwork - Access to data with multiple includes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Application (
    Student VARCHAR(40),
    CrsId INTEGER,
    DateOfApplication DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT StudentApplies
        FOREIGN KEY (Student) 
        REFERENCES EducationUser (UsrName),
    CONSTRAINT CourseExists 
        FOREIGN KEY (CrsId) 
        REFERENCES Course (Id),
    PRIMARY KEY (Student, CrsId, DateOfApplication)
);

CREATE TABLE EducationUser (
    UsrName VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
...
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
...
    CONSTRAINT crsInProgram 
        FOREIGN KEY (CrsProgId) 
        REFERENCES Program (Id),
    CONSTRAINT teacherInUser
        FOREIGN KEY (Teacher)
        REFERENCES EducationUser (UsrName)
);
```

I want to list all courses, and fetch related `EducationUser` and `Application` data, and then list all the courses a user is subscribed to (and some other stuff which works fine).

For this, I created

```
public IEnumerable<Course> Courses
{
    get
    {
        return _entities.Course.Include("EducationUser").Include("Application");
    }
}
```

Then I load this as a `Model`. I'm trying to list the courses in a `View`:

```
@for (Int32 i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Model[i].Application.Student == ViewBag.CurrentGuestName) // THIS LINE IS NOT RIGHT
    {
         //display it
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to access `Model[i].Application.Student`. What am I missing? Apparently `ICollection<Application> does not contain definition for Student`. I'm sorry if it's a noob one, I am just getting aquainted with this.

Comment: I think you have to replace your `for` cycle with `foreach(var course in Model) { if(course.Application.Student == ViewBag.CurrentGuestName) { // display it } }`

Comment: That doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I could be wrong, but your `Course` entity should have `ICollection<Application>`, because you have many application with reference to one course, isn't it?

Comment: I need `public IEnumerable<Course> Courses` as in an other use (when the user is not logged in), I just list all the courses. I just want to filter the courses to the ones that the user is subscribed to, in case the user is logged in.

Comment: What is the type of your `Model` ?

Comment: `@model PagedList.IPagedList<Practice.Models.Course>`

Comment: Ok, so your database scheme looks like your `Course` could be the parent of multiple `Application`, because you have reference like `Application.CrsId`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Your model seems to be incorrect. You are adding a FK to Program table but it does not exists. By the way, it's a bad preactice send a entity framework collection direclty to UI. You could make a Model/POCO/DTO object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Exception message `ICollection<Application> does not contain definition for Student` tell you, that your `Course` entity has collection of applications in your class and it's not correct to access `Application` like this: `Model[i].Application`.

You have to change your current code like this:

```
@foreach(var course in Model) {
    if(course.Application.Any(a => a.Student == ViewBag.CurrentGuestName) {
        //display it        
    }
}
```